# Thurlby PL310 bench power supply: what does these resistors do?

Tags: schematics

I have an issue with my PSU showing 'ofl' on its voltmeter, despite the output working fine.

Could you explain to me what the resistors in the red box are for and why it needs them?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you give us the part number for IC3 and a link to the datasheet? "Thurlby" and "PL" should be capitalised.

Comment: A lot of black boxes, but with the fine tuning of these pots, I suspect it is for calibration of gain/offset for some parameter of the ADC or DAC

Comment: oh sorry it's an add3701

Comment: though trial and error i believe R27 is where the output voltage goes in yes?